# Edit control capture enter key

Tags: c++, winapi

I have an edit control

```
HWND hInput = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "EDIT", "", 
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL, 
    0, 0, 100, 100, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_INPUT, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
```

and a button:

```
HWND hSendButton = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,"BUTTON","Send!",
        BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
        0,0,0,0,hwnd,(HMENU)IDC_MAIN_SENDBUTTON,GetModuleHandle(NULL),NULL);
```

Is there a way to see when the Enter key is pressed while typing in the edit control
and send a message like the button was pressed?

I think that maybe

```
SendMessage(hwnd,WM_COMMAND,(WPARAM)IDC_MAIN_SENDBUTTON,LPARAM(0));
```

would do the job for sending the message but I'm still stuck at capturing the Enter key.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The traditional way of doing this is to declare an accelerator table that defines ENTER as mapping to `IDC_MAIN_SENDBUTTON`. Note also that `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` is not best practice since it puts your windows in the namespace of the primary executable rather than the module that created the window.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to subclass the edit control and handle WM_KEYDOWN message. If it's the key you want, send the message, otherwise, let the default edit control procedure do its job.

The code would like this:

```
WNDPROC oldEditProc;

LRESULT CALLBACK subEditProc(HWND wnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   switch (msg)
   {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
         switch (wParam)
         {
          case VK_RETURN:
          //Do your stuff
              break;  //or return 0; if you don't want to pass it further to def proc
          //If not your key, skip to default:
         }
    default:
         return CallWindowProc(oldEditProc, wnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
   }
   return 0;
}

void somecreateeditproc()
{
  HWND hInput = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "EDIT", "", 
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL, 
    0, 0, 100, 100, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_INPUT, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

  oldEditProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(hInput, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)subEditProc);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I do it in dialog:

```
BOOL CDialogObject::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN && pMsg->wParam == VK_RETURN)
    {
        SendMessage(WM_COMMAND, (WPARAM)IDC_BUTTON3,LPARAM(0));
    }
    return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method suggested by the current answer is old. According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview), there is a slightly easier way to subclass a control.

> The following example shows a skeleton implementation of a window procedure for a subclassed control.

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK OwnerEditProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
                               LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        .
        .
        .
        return TRUE;
    // Other cases...
    } 
    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

> The window procedure can be attached to the control in the `WM_INITDIALOG` handler of the dialog procedure, as shown in the following example.

```cpp
case WM_INITDIALOG:
{
    HWND control = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_EDIT);
    SetWindowSubclass(control, OwnerEditProc, 0, 0);
    return TRUE;
}
```